# Замена стандртных социальных кнопок на кастомные

Tags: java, android, xml

Решил заменить две стандартные кнопки от социальных сетей, на кастомные.

Вот код стандарных которые были.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/facebook_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/google_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="268dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Вот собственно одна их кастомных:

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/facebook_login"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
```

В классе где расположены кнопки заменил на ImageButton:

```
        facebookLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);
```

И сразу посыпались ошибки:

```
facebookLogin.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    facebookLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
```

Мол нельзя решить данные методы, не пойму почему так и как можно исправить, ведь ничего такого я не добавлял.

Comment: `не пойму почему так` -- Вы серьезно? Вы понимаете, что на объекте класса нельзя вызвать метод, которого в этом классе нет?

Comment: @post_zeew а как тогда можно использовать кастомные кнопки для facebook/gmail и т д?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под словом `кастомные`?

Comment: @post_zeew ну вот то что я создал ImageButton, до этого использовал com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton и всё работало, только была прямоугольная кнопка, которую по умолчанию предлагает fb. Может быть их возможно как то объеденить?

Answer (score 1):

у ImageButton нету метода setReadPermissions, вот она и ругаеться

Comment: А можно как то унаследовать?) или как можно решить данную пробелмку?)